# How to insert Wordpress permalinks in E-Mails automatically in a BackOffice System

Tags: c#, wordpress, vb.net, schema, permalinks

how to insert Wordpress permalinks in E-Mails automatically in a BackOffice System?

We have a BackOffice System developed with .NET (C# and VB.Net).
Inside this System we can generate product offers from our backoffice database for our customers and sent them via E-Mail.

Now we want to use WordPress as our Website Frontoffice.
Each Product has it´s own Post and it´s own Permalink.
Right now we use /%postname%/ as Permalink structure.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

When a client ask for a product, we want to sent him an offer with details coming from our BackOffice System and Database and a deep-link to the product on the WordPress Website within the E-Mail.

How can we insert the URL to a certain WordPress Post (= Product) in our E-Mail automatically via program code?
Is there any function / API in WordPress where I can get the used structure of the deep-link URL?
How can I get all the links to all post and pages of our WordPress Website, e.g to save them in our database to the certain product?

Can I extract the URL schema of the Site in anyhow?
Shall I use the original URL or the rewritten human friendly URL?

What about the new Rest-API from WordPress 4.7 and above?
Is there any function to get the URLs?

Thanks for your hints.

Rene